# Rails/ActiveRecord: What is the correct way to establish a many to many association where one side is polymorphic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `Badge`, `Comment` and `Project`. Comments and projects can have many badges. A badge can have many comments and projects.

Badges point to comments and projects through a join table named reactions.

```
# reaction.rb
class Reaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :badge
  belongs_to :reaction_target, polymorphic: true
end

# badge.rb
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions
  has_many :reaction_targets, through: :reactions
end

# comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions, as: :reaction_target
  has_many :badges, through: :reactions
end

# project.rb
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions, as: :reaction_target
  has_many :badges, through: :reactions
end
```

I can now add badges to the reaction targets:

```
> @comment.badges << Badge.first_or_create(name: "test")
=> [#<Badge:0x00007fcff7619d28
  id: 1,
  name: "test",
  created_at: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 18:25:54 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sat, 23 Feb 2019 18:25:54 UTC +00:00>]
```

But I can't do the inverse:

```
> Badge.first_or_create(name: "test").reaction_targets << @comment
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationPolymorphicSourceError: Cannot have
a has_many :through association 'Badge#reaction_targets' on the
polymorphic object 'ReactionTarget#reaction_target' without 'source_type'.
Try adding 'source_type: "ReactionTarget"' to 'has_many :through'
definition. from /Users /elephant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5
.2.2/lib/active_record/reflecti on.rb:932:in `check_validity!'
```

I'm not quite sure why it's suggesting I specify the source type when my associations are supposed to be polymorphic. However, I've tried:

```
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions
  has_many :reaction_targets, through: :reactions, source_type: "ReactionTarget"
end
```

But then I get an error:

```
> Badge.first_or_create(name: "test").reaction_targets
NameError: uninitialized constant Badge::ReactionTarget
```

I'm struggling to get a handle on this. What am I missing? Where have I gone wrong? What is preventing me from being able to determine the reaction targets from the badge side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR:

**app/models/badge.rb**

```
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions
  
  has_many :reaction_target_comments, through: :reactions, source: :reaction_target, source_type: 'Comment'
  has_many :reaction_target_projects, through: :reactions, source: :reaction_target, source_type: 'Project '
  # ... etc
end
```

### Explanation

As far as I know  for polymorphic many-to-many association, you cannot do

```
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reaction_targets, through: :reactions
  # ...
end
```

...(will raise an error just as you have observed), because if this is possible, this means that doing `badge.reaction_targets` should return an Array of "different-model"-instances, i.e:

```
badge = Badge.find(1)
puts badge.reaction_targets.to_a
# => [<Comment id: 1>,
#     <Project id: 45>,
#     <SomeModel id: 99>,
#     <COmment id: 3>,
#     ...]
```

^ The code above looks really intuitive right? ... because it should return an Array of different-typed records, which perfectly makes sense because it's a polymorphic relationship, right? Yes this is perfectly true, but it becomes problematic on what SQL string should be generated. See, a sample SQL equivalent below:

```
puts badge.reaction_targets
# =>  SELECT "WHAT_TABLE_1".* FROM "WHAT_TABLE_1" INNER JOIN reactions ...
#     SELECT "WHAT_TABLE_2".* FROM "WHAT_TABLE_2" INNER JOIN reactions ...
#     SELECT "WHAT_TABLE_3".* FROM "WHAT_TABLE_3" INNER JOIN reactions ...
#     ... etc
```

^ ...because `reaction_targets` is expected to have differing-model-instances, then imagine what SQL above should be needed to perform to get all records? Although, I think it's possible to get all of them, but it would probably not be a direct SQL statement, but probably having combination of some application-side Ruby-code logic. And also, the return type should not be a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, but probably a new type of object specifically just to cater this `has_many` polymorphic relationship. I mean imagine if you do something like below otherwise:

```
badge.reaction_targets.where(is_enabled: true, first_name: 'Hello')
# or even more complex:
badge.reaction_targets.joins(:users).where(users: { email: 'email@example.com' }).
```

^ ... I don't think there is a direct SQL statement to the just that above for polymorphic joins, and so this is perhaps why you are required to add a `source` and `source_type` for different "models", just like my answer above.

### Possible Workaround

If you are fine returning an `Array` object instead of the normal `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` object, you can do something like below. (Though you still have to specify each polymorphic `has_many` relationship, and possibly add more in the future.)

```
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reactions

  has_many :reaction_target_comments, through: :reactions, source: :reaction_target, source_type: 'Comment'
  has_many :reaction_target_projects, through: :reactions, source: :reaction_target, source_type: 'Project'

  def reaction_targets
    reaction_target_comments.to_a + reaction_target_projects.to_a
  end
end
```

#### Usage Example:

```
badge = Badge.find(1)
puts badge.reaction_targets
# =>[<Comment id: 1>,
#    <Comment id: 45>,
#    <Project id: 99>,
#    <Project id: 3>,
#    ...]
```